# No connection to internet

Tags: networking, internet

I have a problem with loss of internet access on 22.04 .
Asus vivo book laptop, I upgraded from 20.04 and it worked fine for about a week and then I lost access to internet. Pings were still returned and my cloud storage ( with its own client) works, both to upload and download. Any connection that uses ubuntu is not working.
I reloaded from cold ( repartition and new base copy of 22.04). To clear all data and everything worked well for about a week and then the same error reoccurred
Nmcli returns :-
wlo1 connected to ( wifi name)
But also returns:-
P2P-dev-wlo1: disconnected
Is this likely to be the issue?
If how can I reconnect it?.
Or any help on this issue
Thanks
Info requested ip addr:-
Transffering results from laptop to phone.:-
2: wlo1: <broadcast, multicast,up,lower_up> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state up group default qlen 1000.

Is other info required?
Edit for future reference:-

A spilt glass of water solved this problem permanently. Fried laptop.

At the time of this fault I ran a standard 22.04 installation with only Invoice ninja, openvpn and cyberghost loaded as extras. My completely uneducated guess is that the openvpn or cyberghost combination were not closing off cleanly as I'm assuming they change the basic Ubuntu network settings as part of their operation. Invoice ninja is just a cloud invoice system using the basic communication protocols from Ubuntu. Not too likely to cause this problem. I stress this is just an uninformed opinion as I never resolved the issue.

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu. Can you add the output of `ip addr` in to your question?

Comment: Please [€dit] the question to add requested information. Do not use comments for that.

Comment: From your question "I reloaded from cold to clear and all worked " please explain what this means. Do you simply mean you rebooted or did you install something? It is not clear.

Comment: IP addr results added to question

Comment: Sorry local terminology : I fully reloaded a new copy of Ubuntu without saving any original data. 
Data was restored from backups